# Invoke ant target from another target with <groovy>

Tags: ant, groovy

I have the following script:

```
<target name="query">
    <taskdef name="groovy" classname="org.codehaus.groovy.ant.Groovy" classpathref="libraries"/>

    <groovy>
    import groovy.sql.Sql

    def sql = Sql.newInstance("jdbc:oracle:thin:@mydomain.com:1521:alias", "test", "test", "oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource")

    List productNames = sql.rows("SELECT name from PRODUCT")

    //println(productNames.count)

    productNames.each {
        println it["name"]
        // HOW TO INVOKE ANT TARGET TASK HERE? TARGET TASK WILL USE it["name"] VALUE
    }

    properties."productNames" = productNames
    </groovy>
</target>

<target name="result" depends="query">
    <echo message="Row count: ${productNames}"/>
</target>
```

I would like to invoke another ant target from "query" target. Especially inside of productNames loop, like put in comments above.

Do you have any idea how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some binding objects in the `<groovy>` scope ([see the documentation for more details](http://groovy.codehaus.org/The+groovy+Ant+Task)), more specifically there is `ant` object which is an instance of `AntBuilder` ([see the api here](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/util/AntBuilder.html)), with this object you can invoke `getProject()` method to get an instance of [`org.apache.tools.ant.Project`](http://api.dpml.net/ant/1.6.5/org/apache/tools/ant/Project.html) and with this `Project` you can use `executeTarget(java.lang.String targetName)` method to execute a different target passing its name. All together looks like: `ant.getProject().executeTarget("yourTargetName")` and in your code:

```
<target name="query">
    <taskdef name="groovy" classname="org.codehaus.groovy.ant.Groovy" classpathref="libraries"/>
        <groovy>
            import groovy.sql.Sql

            def sql = Sql.newInstance("jdbc:oracle:thin:@mydomain.com:1521:alias", "test", "test", "oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource")

            List productNames = sql.rows("SELECT name from PRODUCT")

            //println(productNames.count)

            productNames.each {
                println it["name"]
                ant.getProject().executeTarget("yourTargetName")
            }

            properties."productNames" = productNames
        </groovy>
</target>
```

**EDIT BASED ON COMMENT:**

Passing parameters to the ant call it's not possible through `org.apache.tools.ant.Project` methods, however there is another way to do so,  using `ant` or `antcall` tasks through `AntBuilder`, using `antcall` however it's not supported inside `<groovy>` if you try to use it you will get this error message:

```
antcall not supported within AntBuilder, consider using 'ant.project.executeTarget('targetName')' instead
```

So you must use `ant` task. For example if you have the follow ant target with a parameter in your `build.xml`:

```
<target name="targetTest">
  <echo message="param1=${param1}"/>
</target>
```

You can call it from `<groovy>` passing a parameter like this:

```
<target name="targetSample">
    <taskdef name="groovy" classname="org.codehaus.groovy.ant.Groovy" classpathref="groovyLibs"/>
      <groovy>
        ant.ant(antfile:'build.xml'){ // you antfile name
           target(name:'targetTest') // your targetName
           property(name:'param1',value:'theParamValue') // your params name and values
        }
       <groovy>
 </target>
```

If you execute this `<groovy>` target example with `ant targetSampe` you will get:

```
targetTest:
     [echo] param1=theParamValue

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 0 seconds
```

Hope this helps,

Comment: Thanks for tip. Do you know how can I add parameter to "yourTargetName" task in executeTarget method? I don't see any additional parameter.

Comment: I'll update my answer to fit you new requirement `:)`